What is the difference between the Penrose Conjecture and the Penrose Inequality?
The Penrose Inequality applies to specific initial data sets in general relativity and has been proven under certain conditions, particularly in asymptotically flat spacetimes with non-negative scalar curvature.
The Penrose Conjecture seems to generalize this inequality, suggesting that it should hold under broader conditions, possibly even in cases that involve more general or less symmetric initial data.
Could someone clarify the primary mathematical difference between these two? Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how the conditions under which they apply differ and why the conjecture remains unproven in general cases while the inequality has been established under certain assumptions.
